# Convert data like :) into a smiley in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a messaging application built with ReactJS. I am using emoji-mart to get the emoji table. And it is working fine but I want it to behave in a manner such that if I type :) in the textbox then it should convert it into its corresponding smiley like this . How can I do it? This is how most of the text application work. Right now :) -> this is being treated as a normal text.

Comment: what is "the emoji table" (format example). are there any codes which allow you to convert ":)" to the corresponding ? do you want to do it live (when written) or on save?

Comment: "The emoji table" I am referring to, is the list of emojis' we get when we click on the emoticon icon, similar to what we get on Facebook. When commenting on facebook, we get an emoticon icon and as we click on it, we get a list of all emojis. 
That is what my question is, how can we convert :) to , I want to do it live, as in, as soon as I write : and ) in the textbox, it should display it as 